# Rails: Delete request in capybara, bug or my mistake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, railstutorial.org

In [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial (Rails 3.2)](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial), in Listing 9.52:

```
      describe "when signing in again" do
        before do
          delete signout_path
          print page.html <---- Insert this here
          visit signin_path
          print page.html <---- Insert here again
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it "should render the default (profile) page" do
          page.should have_selector('title', text: user.name) 
        end
      end
```

I inserted those two prints. And, surprisingly I got the printout of the same page (which shouldn't be, It was supposed to bring you back to the root url after sending the `DELETE` request). After this happens, since `visit signin_path` takes me back to the sign in page, the sign in procedure succeeds and so does the test case. However, the second `print page.html` gave me the header of a user whom is still signed in.

When I changed `delete signout_path` to `click_link "Sign out"`, it worked.

Did I miss something in my code or it's a Capybara bug? (Cause I'm pretty sure I followed everything just right..)

**UPDATE:**
If I change `delete signout_path` to `Capybara.current_session.driver.delete signout_path` it also works just fine. (Meaning capybara signs out the user correctly)

**UPDATE**

These are the files (sessions controller and helper):

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  ...

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  ...

end
```

Comment: Your code for `authentication_pages_spec.rb` looks correct. Can you show your controller and routes files?

Comment: @halmeetdave I just updated the question

Comment: Your code looks good. You may have found a bug in Capybara. I'm too new to Rails to confirm or deny this though.

Comment: Since the hardcode (`Capybara.current_session.driver.delete`) works, I'm sensing there's something wrong with either Capybara, or my spec_helper.rb, or the other gems versions..

Comment: @halmeetdave Okay thanks for checking out. I'll post something to the dev ml.

Answer (score 3):

`delete signout_path` does not work on Capybara feature specs. `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete` are Controller spec specific methods and are not available in feature specs.

You also want to be making actual requests (via click, submit, etc...) in Capybara specs since that is generally what you are trying to test.

If you want to ensure a session is clear as a "setup" it's best to do it via the model.

*As an aside, if you look at what you are describing "when signing in again", you probably want to actually "log out" so you can actually "sign in again".*

Comment: Are you saying that `delete` method (or `Capybara.current_session.driver.delete`) shouldn't be there in the first place?

Comment: Well, it's not the general practice to use those methods for a feature/acceptance type test. You want to use the full stack to run through your scenarios.

Comment: The `delete` method is actually a method in `Rack::Test`, and it starts a different session than your Capybara session. [Here's an article that explains it](http://www.elabs.se/blog/34-capybara-and-testing-apis).

Answer (score 2):

You can try following:

```
page.driver.submit :delete, '/users/sign_out', {}
```